# How to pass an object to HTTPOST method from angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I wanted to pass an object to my controller using $http method. But my data passed is NULL, though the object has a value. Below is the sample code.

in my js file, I have an object like this:

```
      $scope.emp ={
                     Name :null,
                      Age:null
                      };

// in a form am capturing the
```

se values, so this.emp has value.

on a submit button click , am trying to send this data to my controller using http method like this:

//my html page

```
<button type="submit" ng-click="saveForm()" >Submit</button>
```

//my js file

```
              $scope.saveForm=function()
             {
              try{
                 $http({
                url:'Employee/SaveEmployee',
                method: "POST",
                data: this.emp,
                }).success(function (response) {

            });
        }
        catch(e){}
           }
```

In debug mode I can see that this.emp has value, but data doesnt. So the value passed to my Controller method is NULL. Can you please me identify the error.

Comment: add `console.log( this.emp);` in you function then Check the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that you are trying to capture data from the form in your controller using bound variable $scope.emp. Once you have the data you want to send the data using $http post.

Your problem is that this.emp is not defined in your current setup. What you want is to replace this.emp with $scope.emp. Your code should look like this:

```
$http.post('Employee/SaveEmployee',$scope.emp)
    .success(function(response) { 
        console.log('Post Successful'); 
};
```